# How to backup/dump structure of graphs in arangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Is there a way to dump the graphstructure of an arangoDB database, since
arangodump unfortunately just dumps the data of edges and collections.

Comment: Have you tried **arangodump --dump-data false --include-system-collections true --output-directory "dump"** where you specify *--dump-data false* and *--include-system-collections true* that should only dump the structural information

Comment: **--include-system-collections true** did the trick. Coming from the sql-world I didn't expect the graph structures within the system-collections. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation in order to dump structural information of all collections (including system collections) you run the following

```
arangodump --dump-data false --include-system-collections true --output-directory "dump"
```

If you do not want the system collections to be included then don't provide the argument (it defaults to false) or provide a false value.

How is the structural and data of collections dumped, see below from the [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Arangodump.html)

> Structural information for a collection will be saved in files with
>   name pattern .structure.json. Each structure file will contains a JSON
>   object with these attributes:
>
> parameters: contains the collection properties
>
> indexes: contains the collection indexes
>
> Document data for a collection will be saved in
>   files with name pattern .data.json. Each line in a data file is a
>   document insertion/update or deletion marker, alongside with some meta
>   data.

Answer (score 1):

For testing I often want to extract a subgraph with a known structure. I use that to test my queries against. The method is not pretty but it might address your question. I blogged about it [here](https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/extracting-test-data-from-arangodbs-admin-interface/).

Answer (score 1):

Although @[Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225551/raf)'s answer is accepted , `--dump-data false` will only give structure files for all the collections and but data wont be there. Including `--include-system-collections true` would give `_graphs` system collection's structure which wont have information pertaining to individual graphs creation/structure.

> **For Graph creation data as well**

Right command is as follows.

```
arangodump --server.database <DB_NAME> --include-system-collections true --output-directory <YOUR_DIRECTORY>
```

We would be interested in `_graphs_<long_id>.data.json` named file which has below data format.

```
{
    "type": 2300,
    "data":
    {
        "_id": "_graphs/social",
        "_key": "social",
        "_rev": "_WaJxhIO--_",
        "edgeDefinitions": [
            {
                "collection": "relation",
                "from": ["female", "male"],
                "to": ["female", "male"]
            }
        ],
        "numberOfShards": 1,
        "orphanCollections": [],
        "replicationFactor": 1
    }
}
```

Hope this helps other users who were looking for my requirement!

Answer (score 0):

Currently ArangoDB manages graphs via documents in the system collection `_graphs`.
One document equals one graph. It contains the [graph name](https://docs.arangodb.com/Glossary/index.html#named-graphs), [involved vertex collections](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphFunctions.html) and [Edge Definition](https://docs.arangodb.com/Glossary/index.html#edge-definition) that configure the directions of edge collections.